# ScrollToItemAtIndexPath for Infinite Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an infinite collection view, and every time it appears, I'd like to display a specific indexPath. I attempted putting the scrollToItemAtIndexPath method in viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, and viewDidLayoutSubviews to no avail.

On viewDidLayoutSubviews, the view shows up properly but displays the wrong index. It ends up being offset by 24 indexes. When I print the index, I see the proper index in the console. When I set the index in cellForItemAtIndexPath, it also displays the proper index, but all of the cells are just that index.

Here is the code I have in viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    infiniteCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.infiniteCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(self.initialIndexPath!, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: false)
}
```

This displays the cell 24 indexes before the one I actually want to be presented. I assume that I'm scrolling the collection view before all the cells are being loaded properly, therefore causing it to display the incorrect index.

How would I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding the scroll to viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work either

Comment: does it scroll horizontally or vertically?

Comment: it scrolls horizontally